# List Comprehension; compacting code to two lines

Tags: python, regex, list, list-comprehension

The basic outline of this problem is to read the file, look for integers using the re.findall(), looking for a regular expression of '[0-9]+' and then converting the extracted strings to integers and summing up the integers.

I have finished the problem, but I would like to go extra and condense the code down to two lines.

This is my original code:

```
import re

fh = raw_input("Enter filename: ")
#returns regex_sum_241882.txt as default when nothing is entered
if len(fh)<1 : fh = "regex_sum_241882.txt"
file = open(fh)
sums = list()
#goes through each line in the file
for line in file:
    #finds the numbers in each line and puts them in a list
    nums = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
    #adds the numbers to an existing list
    for num in nums:
        sums.append(int(num))
#sums the list
print sum(sums)
```

Now here's my current compact code:

```
import re
lst = list()
print sum(for num in re.findall('[0-9]+',open("regex_sum_241882.txt").read())): int(num))
```

It doesn't work and gives me *SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

Can anyone point me in the right direction? 
I feel I'm doing the same thing, but I'm not sure what the syntaxerror is about.

Comment: You need to look at how generator expressions are structured: it's `(item for item in iterable)`, not `(for item in iterable: item)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
print sum(int(num) for num in re.findall('[0-9]+', open("regex_sum_241882.txt").read()))
```

Comment: You could get more of the original code in too using `... open(raw_input("Enter filename: ") or "regex_sum_241882.txt").read()`